# openann c++ compilation fail

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++

I have a problem compiling some c++ code with OpenANN.
I wonder if you can help me, here is the log of make:
[log](http://pastebin.com/SLz2qTcT)

I have installed he dependancies for OpenANN.

---

Errors from link:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3  main.cpp  -I/usr/include/eigen3 -L/usr/include/OpenANN -L/usr/lib -lutil -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams -o Bot.out:

/tmp/cc78iiwc.o: dans la fonction « Brain::ComputeTarget(Brain::MemCell const&) »:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5Brain13ComputeTargetERKNS_7MemCellE[_ZN5Brain13ComputeTargetERKNS_7MemCellE]+0xa7): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::operator()(Eigen::Matrix const&) »
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5Brain13ComputeTargetERKNS_7MemCellE[_ZN5Brain13ComputeTargetERKNS_7MemCellE]+0x18d): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::operator()(Eigen::Matrix const&) »
/tmp/cc78iiwc.o: dans la fonction « main »:
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2cf): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::operator()(Eigen::Matrix const&) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa16): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::DirectStorageDataSet::DirectStorageDataSet(Eigen::Matrix*, Eigen::Matrix*, OpenANN::Evaluator*) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa2f): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Learner::trainingSet(OpenANN::DataSet&) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa3c): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::StoppingCriteria::StoppingCriteria() »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa8d): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::train(OpenANN::Net&, std::string, OpenANN::ErrorFunction, OpenANN::StoppingCriteria const&, bool, bool) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xbf4): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::save(std::string const&) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xfd5): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::operator()(Eigen::Matrix const&) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1064): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::operator()(Eigen::Matrix const&) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x11f6): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::DirectStorageDataSet::DirectStorageDataSet(Eigen::Matrix*, Eigen::Matrix*, OpenANN::Evaluator*) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x120f): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Learner::trainingSet(OpenANN::DataSet&) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x121c): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::StoppingCriteria::StoppingCriteria() »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x126d): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::train(OpenANN::Net&, std::string, OpenANN::ErrorFunction, OpenANN::StoppingCriteria const&, bool, bool) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15f6): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::DirectStorageDataSet::DirectStorageDataSet(Eigen::Matrix*, Eigen::Matrix*, OpenANN::Evaluator*) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x160f): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Learner::trainingSet(OpenANN::DataSet&) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x161c): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::StoppingCriteria::StoppingCriteria() »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x166d): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::train(OpenANN::Net&, std::string, OpenANN::ErrorFunction, OpenANN::StoppingCriteria const&, bool, bool) »
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1900): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::~Net() »
/tmp/cc78iiwc.o: dans la fonction « Brain::Brain() »:
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5BrainC2Ev[_ZN5BrainC5Ev]+0x37): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::Net() »
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5BrainC2Ev[_ZN5BrainC5Ev]+0x58): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::load(std::string const&) »
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5BrainC2Ev[_ZN5BrainC5Ev]+0x115): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::inputLayer(int, int, int) »
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5BrainC2Ev[_ZN5BrainC5Ev]+0x134): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::fullyConnectedLayer(int, OpenANN::ActivationFunction, double, bool) »
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5BrainC2Ev[_ZN5BrainC5Ev]+0x153): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::outputLayer(int, OpenANN::ActivationFunction, double, bool) »
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5BrainC2Ev[_ZN5BrainC5Ev]+0x16d): référence indéfinie vers « OpenANN::Net::~Net() »
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
Makefile:6 : la recette pour la cible « test » a échouée
make: *** [test] Erreur 1
```

Comment: Those are not really compiler errors, but *linker* errors, and they say that you are missing many symbols from the OpenANN library, presumably because you don't link with it. (At least I'm guessing that, because I don't read French (I guess it is), few here do. Please change locale so you get English output in the future when you post questions.)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I confirm it's French, and it's indeed "missing reference to" that is translated.

Answer (score 2):

Your compilation command is erroneous.

> ```
> g++ -std=c++11 -O3  main.cpp  -I/usr/include/eigen3 -L/usr/include/OpenANN \
>     -L/usr/lib -lutil -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams -o Bot.out
> ```

The link options that are `-L` and `-l` have two different roles:

- `-L` means to consider the directory when looking for libraries
- `-l` means to link with this library

If you look exactly at the flags concerning `OpenANN` that you pass you will realize that you instructed `g++` too look into the `/usr/include/OpenANN` directory when searching for libraries, but never actually instruct it to link against the `OpenANN` library.

If `g++` is not instructed to link the program/library with the `OpenANN` library it will not, and you'll get undefined symbols.